Import aliases are not working in the Cloudflare or Render
This is my ts config file:
{
....,
  "paths": {
   "@/*": [
    "./src/*"
   ],
  }
 },
 "include": [
  "src",
 ],
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "dist"
 ],
 "references": [
  {
   "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
  }
 ]
}

And this is my vite config file I am using vite v6.1:
import { TanStackRouterVite } from "@tanstack/router-vite-plugin";
// import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [react({
  babel: {
   plugins: [
    ["babel-plugin-react-compiler", { target: '19' }] // Add the React Compiler plugin with target version
   ],
  },
 }), TanStackRouterVite(), tsconfigPaths()],
 resolve: {
  alias: {
   "@/": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
  }
 }
});

I've tried various methods, but I'm unable to resolve the issue - any help appreciated.
I try to deploy in Render, I tried to deploy in Cloudflare, both failed with the same error message:
==> Build failed 
src/routes/__root.tsx(1,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/components/header' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/routes/(landing)/_landing.tsx(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/components/footer' or its corresponding type declarations.
$ tsc && vite build

